# IAM role to allow command execution on AWS ECS containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to both terraform, and AWS. I am trying to set `enable_execute_command=true` on an existing fargate service, with the role and cluster/service/task defined liked this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_execution_role_base" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
 
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
 
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ecs_exec_policy" {
  name = "ecs_exec_policy"
 
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action   = ["ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                    "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                    "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                    "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
                    ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      },
    ]
  })
}
 
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name               = var.ecs_task_execution_role_name
 
  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_execution_role_base.json
  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole", aws_iam_policy.ecs_exec_policy.arn]
 
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  name = "backendcluster"
}
 
data "template_file" "backendapp" {
  template = file("./templates/ecs/backend_app.json.tpl")
 
  vars = {
    server_image      = var.server_image
    celery_image      = var.celery_image
    app_port       = var.app_port
    fargate_cpu    = var.fargate_cpu
    fargate_memory = var.fargate_memory
    aws_region     = var.aws_region
    database_host = aws_db_instance.default.address
    database_port = aws_db_instance.default.port
    redis_host = aws_elasticache_cluster.default.cache_nodes.0.address
    redis_port = aws_elasticache_cluster.default.cache_nodes.0.port
  }
}
 
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family                   = "backend-app-task"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.fargate_cpu
  memory                   = var.fargate_memory
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.backendapp.rendered
}
 
resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  name            = "backendservice"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn
  desired_count   = var.app_count
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  enable_execute_command = true
 
  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id]
    subnets          = aws_subnet.private.*.id
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
 
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.id
    container_name   = "server"
    container_port   = var.app_port
  }
 
  depends_on = [aws_alb_listener.backend]
}
```

Running `terraform apply` gives:

```
Error: error updating ECS Service (arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:00000000:service/backendcluster/backendservice): InvalidParameterException: The service couldn't be updated because a valid taskRoleArn is not being used. Specify a valid task role in your task definition and try again.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app"` you have specified an `execution_role_arn`, but you have not specified a `task_role_arn`. That's really what the error is saying, that you need to provide a task role ARN.

The execution role gives the ECS service permission to do things like read an image from an ECR repository, and lookup secrets in SecretsManager that it needs to inject into the containers it creates.

The task role gives the software running inside the ECS task/container permission to access AWS resources. The command execution permissions need to be assigned to the task role, not the execution role.

At a minimum you could try adding:

```
task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
```

But following the [principal of least privilege](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/access-management/principle-of-least-privilege/) would dictate you separate those roles into separate IAM roles with distinct privileges.

Comment: Ah, understood, thank you. Out of curiosity, if I remove the enable_execute_command line, it seems to be happy, and the service runs. Does it use some default role?

Comment: No there is no default role. When you removed `enable_execute_command` there were no other permissions needed.